# Java. Factory creation should return Generic class

Tags: java, factory

Could someone please help.
I would like to create a Factory, which would return specific class.

Having problem on the line - `filterFactory.getFilter(myColumn.getType()).setMin(5);`
There is an error: Cannot resolve method 'setMin' in 'Object'

```
public enum Columns {
  Name(ColumnType.String),
  Age(ColumnType.Numeric);

  private final ColumnType type;

  Columns(ColumnType type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public ColumnType getType() {
    return type;
  }
}

public enum ColumnType {
  String,
  Numeric
}


public class NumericFilter extends ColumnFilter {
  public void setMin(int min) {
    System.out.println("min is set" + min);
  }
}

public class StringFilter extends ColumnFilter {
  public void setFilter(String filter) {
    System.out.println("filter is set to:" + filter);
  }
}

public class ColumnFilterFactory {
  public <T> T getFilter(ColumnType type) {
    if (type == null) {
      return null;
    }
    if (type == ColumnType.String) {
      return (T) new StringFilter();

    } else if (type == ColumnType.Numeric) {
      return (T) new NumericFilter();
    }

    return null;
  }
}

public class BasicTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Columns myColumn = Columns.Age;
    ColumnFilterFactory filterFactory = new ColumnFilterFactory();
    filterFactory.getFilter(myColumn.getType()).setMin(5);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? Are you getting any error? Add the whole message/stacktrace.

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'setMin' in 'Object'

Comment: Is setMin part of the super class ColumnFilter and shouldn't T be defined as `<T extends ColumnFilter>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way the compiler can know what type the factory is going to return, so you need to give it a little help. For example by using an intermediate variable:

```
NumericFilter nf = filterFactory.getFilter(myColumn.getType());
nf.setMin(5);
```

Comment: so whats the purpose of writing factory here if we know the return type will be ```NumericFilter```

Comment: Is that a question for the OP of for me? The usual benefits of a factory are that you don't have to know *how* the instance is built or *which concrete implementation* of NumericFilter it will return (in case there are several)

Comment: thanks. its for your but ```ColumnFilter``` is our abstract class here. is type of nf correct in your answer? i think nf type should be ```ColumnFilter```